#  Samsung Galaxy S : Why can't I set cursor position in text boxes in browser?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

When using the default browser on my Galaxy S, I can't see a cursor in text boxes that have focus. With no cursor I don't know where letters I type will appear. This seems to occur on all sites I have tested. Can someone with this phone confirm there is something wrong? Note that the address bar at the top is fine and behaves as I would expect.

Input method is the Samsung keyboard. No third party apps or firmware installed. Feel free to ask questions if you need more info. Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce on my T-Mobile Vibrant (I tried all three keyboards).

Answer (score 5):

Press and hold the **?123** key at the bottom, left corner of the standard Samsung Galaxy S keyboard. The keyboard switches to a four arrow cursor pad that you can use to move around a text field. There's also a delete key, select, cut, copy, and paste; click the *Text* key to switch back into keyboard mode.

This works with just about all text fields in all applications that I use.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that ! Just received mhy Galaxy S last week and learning something new every day. This site certainly helps.

Comment: Great tip, Erik. And from the Swype keyboard you activate the arrow keys layout by swyping from the special "(i)" key, in the lower left, to the SYM key - SEE http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/snap20100701_000448_thumb.png from http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/07/02/tip-how-to-get-arrowcursor-keys-on-the-swype-keyboard/

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: I've had this phone for months, and had no idea it had arrow keys.  LIFESAVER.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried on my Samsung Galaxy S with the search box at the top of this page in the built-in browser and I get a flashing cursor all the time I'm not typing (it disappears while I'm typing but comes back if I pause for a moment) I'm using the built-in Swype keyboard.

Also tried switching back to the Samsung Keyboard (by long-pressing on a text field, then selecting Input Method and selecting Samsung Keyboard) and still see a cursor in the search box on this web site.

My Galaxy's running the standard Samsung version of Android 2.1, pretty sure I don't have any apps installed that affect the keyboard or browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different browser. Also you could try going into settings, apllications, manage applications, find the browser you are using and clear data, if that option isn't there, try cache. Reboot and see what happens.

Comment: I switched the phone off and on again and the problem seems to have gone away for the moment. I keep an eye on it for a few days to see if it comes back.

Comment: Glad to hear things are back to normal. Most quirks are fixed by a reboot. I should of suggested that as option 1.